EF Core API making proper many-to-many query
I  am quite new to EF core and C# generally.
I am trying to understand how to make proper query from in between tables that EF core made for me.
public class Device
{
    public Guid Id {get ; set;}
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int  Release_Year { get; set; }
    public double RentPrice { get; set; }
    public double PurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category>? DeviceCategory { get; set; } = default!;
    public Guid AppUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{ 
   public Guid Id {get ; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Guid AppUserId { get; set; }
   public AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }
}

Below I attached ERD, EF Core made for me after migrating and creating database.
I'm trying to get the Device and attach all the Categories that Device belongs to from my API controller but I am a bit confused how to do it since I don't have dbset for CategoryDevice table.
// GET: api/Devices/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Device>> GetDevice(Guid id)
{
    var device = await _context.Devices.FindAsync(id);
            
    if (device == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return device;
}

At the moment my deviceCategory is null if I try to make GET request:
{
    "model": "sony camera",
    "description": "cool camera",
    "release_Year": 2055,
    "rentPrice": 33.23,
    "purchasePrice": 55.3,
    "deviceCategory": null,
    "appUserId": "155f58bb-bd41-4213-9ea0-5a7fc0847ebc",
    "appUser": null,
    "id": "31d1d653-88ff-4f57-a05c-dfb6a9768291"
},



By default EF core won't fetch the related entities from the database. If you want to fetch the main entity and the related entities too, you need to ask EF core to do that.
There are several ways to do that: you can find a complete list here.
The easiest way to load related entities is the eager loading approach. With this approach you eagerly load the related entities when you fetch the main entity from the database. This will lead to a single database query, which will contain one or more joins.
Please, refer to the linked documentation for all the details.
In you case, if you want to use an eager loading approach, you can do this way:
var device = await _context
  .Devices
  .Include(x => x.DeviceCategory)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(id);

This should be enough to resolve your problem.
A possible point of improvement here is defining proper data transfer objects (see here) to be used in the presentation layer only, containing the bare minimum amount of data you want to expose to the API clients.
By doing so, you avoid exposing your domain entities directly to your consumers and you decouple your domain layer and your presentation layer. This will lead to easier maintenance over time (see this and this).
This is an example of such an approach:
public sealed class CategoryDto 
{
  public string Name { get; init; }
}

public sealed class DeviceDto 
{
  public Guid Id {get ; init;}
  public string Model { get; init; }
  public string Description { get; init; }
  public IReadOnlyList<CategoryDto> Categories { get; init; } = new List<CategoryDto>();
}

var device = await _context
  .Devices
  .Select(d => new DeviceDto 
  {
    Id = d.Id,
    Model = d.Model,
    Description = d.Description,
    Categories = d.Categories.Select(c => new CategoryDto 
    {
      Name = c.Name 
    }).ToList()
  })
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(id);

